# Help me fix my packagaes

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

Recently I tried to install gcc and g++6 on my ubuntu distribution but something broke and gcc and g++ 5.3 got uninstalled along with cuda. I fixed it by using aptitude to install cuda and got g++ and gcc and some libs back

Now every time I try to run an `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` I get this

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-cublas-9-0 cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 cuda-cudart-9-0 cuda-cudart-dev-9-0
  cuda-cufft-9-0 cuda-cufft-dev-9-0 cuda-curand-9-0 cuda-curand-dev-9-0
  cuda-cusolver-9-0 cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0 cuda-cusparse-9-0
  cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0 cuda-driver-dev-9-0 cuda-libraries-9-0
  cuda-libraries-dev-9-0 cuda-license-9-0 cuda-misc-headers-9-0 cuda-npp-9-0
  cuda-npp-dev-9-0 cuda-nvgraph-9-0 cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0 cuda-nvml-dev-9-0
  cuda-nvrtc-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libdrm-dev
  libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev
  libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev
  libxdamage-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
  libxshmfence-dev libxxf86vm-dev mesa-common-dev nvidia-modprobe
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev
  x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bbswitch-dkms build-essential cuda cuda-9-0 cuda-command-line-tools-9-0
  cuda-core-9-0 cuda-demo-suite-9-0 cuda-documentation-9-0 cuda-drivers
  cuda-runtime-9-0 cuda-samples-9-0 cuda-toolkit-9-0 cuda-visual-tools-9-0
  dkms g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 libcuda1-384 nvidia-384 nvidia-384-dev
  nvidia-opencl-icd-384 nvidia-prime
The following packages will be upgraded:
  albert code cpp-5 gcc-5-base libasan2 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-common libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2 libdrm2:i386
  libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgcc-5-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libmpx0 libobjc-5-dev libstdc++-5-dev
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libxatracker2 mesa-common-dev slack-desktop
34 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 23 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 122 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,411 MB disk space will be freed.
```

It seems like cuda, gcc and g++ are going to be removed again. How would I fix this?

EDIT:

This is the command that broke gcc and g++ to begin with

```
sudo apt-get update && \\nsudo apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common -y && \\nsudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y && \\nsudo apt-get update && \\nsudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot -y && \\nsudo apt-get update && \\nsudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6 -y && \\nsudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 && \\nsudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 -y && \\nsudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
```

Comment: Egad. I would *never* run such a dangerous set of commands at once. One at a time, and carefully reading for error messages after each. What happens when you explicitly mark cuda for installation? `sudo apt install cuda`

Comment: I was TAing a course and some people used gcc6 to build their code :(. 
I did manage to install cuda using aptitude and one of the alternate solutions it suggested. I just don't want cuda and gcc to be uninstalled everytime I run `dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apt keeps track of the packages that you specify using a system called *apt-marking*.

Apt will only try to autoremove dependencies. That's important. Apt won't autoremove anything you *explicitly* say you want installed until you explicitly say that you want it uninstalled.

It's that simple.

There are several ways to tell apt what you want. These commands both change the apt-marking:

```
sudo apt install packagename       (also installs the package, if not already installed)
sudo apt-mark manual packagename   (changes the marking only)
```

Example: If you want to keep the `cuda` and `gcc` packages and prevent autoremoval: `sudo apt install cuda gcc`

For more information see `man apt-mark`

Comment: but I don't want to manually mark a whole bunch of packages, ones that cuda and gcc depend on! I don't want the stuff listed in packages that will be removed to actually be removed. I never told apt to remove them!

Comment: You don't need to apt-mark "a whole bunch of packages"....just the two. It would indeed be silly for apt to autoremove dependencies of an installed package, so it doesn't. You likely DID tell apt to remove the gcc and cuda, you just don't realize how you did so. In ten years of working with apt, I have never seen it randomly remove packages for fun.

Comment: I toyed around with apt-mark and fixed my problem. Thanks :)